# How to use pt file

Tags: python, computer-vision, yolov5

I'm trying to make a currency recognition model and I did so using a dataset on kaggle and colab using yolov5 and I exactly carried out the steps explained on yolov5 github. At the end, I downloaded a .pt file which has the weights of the model and now I want to use it in python file to detect and recognize currency . How to do this?

I am a beginner in computer vision and I am totally confused about what to do. I am searching over and over but I don't reach anything.

```
import torch

# Model
model=torch.load('E:\_best.pt')

# Images
imgs=['E:\Study\currency.jpg']

# Inference
results = model(imgs)

# Results
results.print()
results.save()  # or .show()
results.show()
results.xyxy[0]  # img1 predictions (tensor)
results.pandas().xyxy[0]
```

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Comment: You need to share your training script (or at least your model definition) so others can better help you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you want to read trained parameters from .pt file and load it into your model, you could do the following.

```py
file = "model.pt"
model = your_model()
model.load_state_dict(torch.load(file))
# this will automatically load the file and load the parameters into the model.
```

before calling load_state_dict(), be sure that the .pt file contains only model parameters, otherwise, error occurs. This can be checked by print(torch.load(file)).

Comment: what is meant by 'your_model()' ? I don't have anything but the .pt file

Comment: your_model() is a class that holds the structure and parameters of the yolov5. It defines the operational rule etc for yolov5. Using Pytorch, you should pay attention to the model definition and copy related .py files then import the model defined in one of those files into your program. If you are still confused, check the [pytorch tutorial](https://pytorch.org/tutorials/beginner/basics/intro.html) for much more detailed information.

Comment: Okay. I downloaded yolov5 from github into my project folder. What is next? Excuse me but it isn't too clear for me.

Comment: What I can do to help is tell you what you need and I cannot write a full tutorial for you here. You need to understand how a task (e.g. classification) is done via PyTorch, which includes dataset preparation, model preparation, training (computing loss and updating parameters ). Reading some tutorials and you will finally make it within hours. And after that don't forget to come back and accept the answer :)

Answer (score 2):

Here is a sample code that can get you started:

```
import torch
from PIL import Image
import numpy as np
import time

# Function to load the model
def load_model(model_path):
    model = torch.load(model_path)
    model.eval()  # Set the model to evaluation mode
    return model

# Function to preprocess the image before feeding it to the model
def preprocess_image(image_path):
    img = Image.open(image_path).convert("RGB")
    img = img.resize((224, 224))  # Resize to the model's expected input size
    img = np.array(img).astype(np.float32) / 255.0  # Convert to a NumPy array and normalize
    img = np.transpose(img, (2, 0, 1))  # Transpose the image to (channels, height, width)
    img = np.expand_dims(img, axis=0)  # Add a batch dimension
    return torch.tensor(img)

# Load the model
model_path = "path/to/your/model.pt"
model = load_model(model_path)

# Load the image and preprocess it
image_path = "path/to/your/image.jpg"
input_image = preprocess_image(image_path)

# Run the model
output = model(input_image)
```